# Measuring time complexity of a method

Tags: functions, performance-tuning

I use

```
NMinimize[someFunction, Method -> {"RandomSearch", Method ->{"InteriorPoint"},"SearchPoints" -> 2n, "RandomSeed" -> RandomInteger[{0, 100}], "PostProcess" -> {FindMinimum, Method -> "QuasiNewton"}}, MaxIterations -> 1000 n, PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10]`
```

where `someFunction` is a function of `n` variables.

How could I measure the time complexity of this method?

Comment: all you can do without acess to the details of the code is emperically evaluate for various n using timing and look at the trend

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a nice function `BenchmarkPlot`

[image]

The usage is something like this

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
BenchmarkPlot[{f1,f2}, # &, PowerRange[1, 1000], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

Typical output:

[image]

There are already many [examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=BenchmarkPlot) on MMA.SE.